# Content Page inside a Tabbed Page using XAML in xamarin.forms

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms

I have a TabbedPage, with 3 childrens.

```
public partial class FactoryDetailsTabs : TabbedPage
    {
        public FactoryDetailsTabs()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Children.Add(new FactoryDetailsTabs_DashboardTab());
            Children.Add(new FactoryDetailsTabs_AnalysisTab());
            Children.Add(new FactoryDetailsTabs_SettingsTab());          

        }
}
```

The 3rd tab contains the settings page. With following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="LogicalSugarDemoApp.Pages.FactoryDetailsTabs_SettingsTab"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:LogicalSugarDemoApp.NativeModels"            
             Title="Settings" Icon="settings">
    <RelativeLayout>
        <Frame x:Name="LanguageFrame" BackgroundColor="Pink">
            <RelativeLayout 
                RelativeLayout.XConstraint=
                     "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,                                                                                                      
                                            Property=Width,
                                            Factor=0.20}"
                 RelativeLayout.YConstraint=
                     "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                            Property=Height,
                                            Factor=10.00}" 
                 RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint=
                     "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                            Property=Width,
                                            Factor=0.40}"
                 RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint=
                     "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                              Property=Height,
                                            Factor=0.05}">
                <Label x:Name="SelectLangLabel" 
                        Text="Select Language"
                        TextColor="Black"
                        BackgroundColor="Teal"
                        FontFamily="Arial"
                        FontSize="30"
                        FontAttributes="Bold"
                     RelativeLayout.XConstraint=
                         "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,                                                                                                      
                                            Property=Width,
                                            Factor=0.02}"
                     RelativeLayout.YConstraint=
                         "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                                Property=Height,
                                                Factor=0.05}" 
                     RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint=
                         "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                                Property=Width,
                                                Factor=0.70}"
                     RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint=
                         "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                                  Property=Height,
                                                Factor=0.10}"/>
                <Picker x:Name="LanguagePicker" 
                        Title="English"
                        BackgroundColor="#e9e9e9"
                     RelativeLayout.XConstraint=
                         "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,                                                                                                      
                                            Property=Width,
                                            Factor=0.76}"
                     RelativeLayout.YConstraint=
                         "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                                Property=Height,
                                                Factor=0.05}" 
                     RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint=
                         "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                                Property=Width,
                                                Factor=0.23}"
                     RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint=
                         "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                                  Property=Height,
                                                Factor=0.10}"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </Frame>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <controls:AdView HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>


</ContentPage>
```

I am not getting any output on this 3rd page inside tabbed page. But when I do this code in a content page outside TabbedPage that works. Please Help. I need it inside the TabbedPage

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of what you're getting in the two different scenarios, cos am getting pink display with some teal lines inside tabbedpage.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add your RelativeLayout to ContentPage.Content. Something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="LogicalSugarDemoApp.Pages.FactoryDetailsTabs_SettingsTab"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:LogicalSugarDemoApp.NativeModels"            
             Title="Settings" Icon="settings">
  <ContentPage.Content>
    <RelativeLayout>
        <Frame x:Name="LanguageFrame" BackgroundColor="Pink">
            <RelativeLayout 
                RelativeLayout.XConstraint=
                     "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,                                                                                                      
                                            Property=Width,
                                            Factor=0.20}"
                 RelativeLayout.YConstraint=
                     "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                            Property=Height,
                                            Factor=10.00}" 
                 RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint=
                     "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                            Property=Width,
                                            Factor=0.40}"
                 RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint=
                     "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                              Property=Height,
                                            Factor=0.05}">
                <Label x:Name="SelectLangLabel" 
                        Text="Select Language"
                        TextColor="Black"
                        BackgroundColor="Teal"
                        FontFamily="Arial"
                        FontSize="30"
                        FontAttributes="Bold"
                     RelativeLayout.XConstraint=
                         "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,                                                                                                      
                                            Property=Width,
                                            Factor=0.02}"
                     RelativeLayout.YConstraint=
                         "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                                Property=Height,
                                                Factor=0.05}" 
                     RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint=
                         "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                                Property=Width,
                                                Factor=0.70}"
                     RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint=
                         "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                                  Property=Height,
                                                Factor=0.10}"/>
                <Picker x:Name="LanguagePicker" 
                        Title="English"
                        BackgroundColor="#e9e9e9"
                     RelativeLayout.XConstraint=
                         "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,                                                                                                      
                                            Property=Width,
                                            Factor=0.76}"
                     RelativeLayout.YConstraint=
                         "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                                Property=Height,
                                                Factor=0.05}" 
                     RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint=
                         "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                                Property=Width,
                                                Factor=0.23}"
                     RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint=
                         "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                                  Property=Height,
                                                Factor=0.10}"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </Frame>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <controls:AdView HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>

  </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

But I don't know if it solve the problem

Comment: do you have some warning in Application console?

Comment: After adding code into <ContentPage.Content> 
</ContentPage.Content> I am getting error as "Sequence contains no element"

Comment: I have copy and paste your code in a Form and I have this result https://www.dropbox.com/s/h5cuf4zovcmskik/Screenshot%202017-04-19%2015.18.23.png?dl=0 (I have only removed last row "AdView")

Comment: I have resolved the issue. That AdView control was out of RelativeLayout so it was not giving me the output and was getting that error as "Sequence contains no element" .